# Как собрать проект на angular2 с помощью gradle?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, gradle, angular2, webpack

Есть проект написанный на [angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), затем я собираю его webpack'ом, получаю 2 файла (app.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js) которые находятся в директории dist. Можно ли как то собрать проект с помощью gradle и потом закинуть его на tomcat? Я с gradle только начал свое знакомство, по этому и возник такой вопрос.
Написал такой вот build.gradle

```
plugins {
id "com.eriwen.gradle.js" version "2.14.1"
id "com.craigburke.client-dependencies" version "1.1.4"
}
apply plugin: "application"
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
providedRuntime
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = "1.12"
} 

clientDependencies {
npm {
    '@angular/common'('2.0.0-rc.4', into: '@angular/common'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    '@angular/compiler'('2.0.0-rc.4', into: '@angular/compiler'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    '@angular/core'('2.0.0-rc.4', into: '@angular/core'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    '@angular/http'('2.0.0-rc.4', into: '@angular/http'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    '@angular/platform-browser'('2.0.0-rc.4', into: '@angular/platform-browser'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'('2.0.0-rc.4', into: '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    '@angular/router'('3.0.0-beta.2', into: '@angular/router'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    '@angular/router-deprecated'('2.0.0-rc.2', into: '@angular/router-deprecated/bundles'){
        include 'router-deprecated.umd.js'
        include 'router-deprecated.umd.min.js'
    }
    '@angular/upgrade'('2.0.0-rc.4', into: '@angular/upgrade'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api'('0.0.14', into: 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'){
        include 'index.js'
    }
    'core-js'('^2.4.0', into: 'core-js/client'){
        include 'shim.js'
        include 'shim.min.js'
    }
    'reflect-metadata'('^0.1.3', into: 'reflect-metadata'){
        include 'Reflect.js'
    }
    'systemjs'('0.19.31', into: 'systemjs/dist'){
        include 'system.src.js'
    }
    'zone.js'('^0.6.12', into: 'zone.js/dist'){
        include 'zone.js'
        include 'zone.min.js'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот так собирает js файлы в варник и добавляет html туда же

```
plugins {
id "com.eriwen.gradle.js" version "2.14.1"
id "com.craigburke.client-dependencies" version "1.1.4"
}
apply plugin: "application"
apply plugin: 'war'
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
providedRuntime
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = "1.12"
} 

war {
from "index.html"

with {
    from "dist/app.bundle.js"
    into '/js/'
}
with {
    from "dist/vendor.bundle.js"
    into '/js/'
}
}
```

Comment: Осталось только сделать так что бы с архива работало

Comment: необходимые css-файлы добавляются аналогично html и js